# Show $n$ is perfect $\iff \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n-2}k\left\lfloor\frac{n}k\right\rfloor=1+\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n-1}k\left\lfloor\frac{n-1}k\right\rfloor$

Tags: proof-verification, summation, prime-numbers, proof-explanation, perfect-numbers

So the question is:

*Prove that $n$ must be a perfect number $\iff$*

$$\sum_{k = 1}^{n - 2}k\left \lfloor\frac{n}{k}\right \rfloor = 1 + \sum_{k = 1}^{n - 1}k \left \lfloor \frac{n - 1}{k}\right\rfloor
$$

I tried looking up about perfect numbers and found this exact equation on Wolfram Alpha Mathworld but all it said was that it was *proven* that $n$ had to equal a perfect number, but I do not know how to prove it. My friend Harry gave me this question knowing that I haven't been taught the skills to prove something like this, but he did give me a hint:

$$\sum_{k = 1}^{2^p - 1}k = \sum_{k = 1}^{2^{(p - 1)/2}}(2k + 1)^3 = (2^{p - 1})(2^p - 1) = \left\{P \mid σ(P) = 2P \land p = prime\right\}$$

Could somebody please help me out and tell me what this means and how would I *say* these equations? I figured out that $2^p - 1 = M_p \iff 2^p - 1 = prime$ such that $M_p$ is a Mersenne prime. I also figured out that $P$ must be a perfect number $\because P = (2^{p - 1})(2^p - 1)$ and that $σ(P) = 2P$ being the divisor function of $P$. I also know what the big sigma $\sum$ means (it means *total sum* or something like that). All of this is thanks to Wolfram Alpha.

But the rest, I don't know what to do. How do I solve something like this?

Comment: There is a typo in the identity, the normal brackets should replaced by the floor function

Comment: I have changed the title of your question for something that may give more information to the reader.  If you preferred the original title, feel free to roll back.

Comment: Oh thanks for changing the brackets in the identity. I thought Harry meant brackets.

Comment: And thanks @Pierre-GuyPlamondon for changing the title. It sounds much more "mathematical" now :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equation to be considered for $n$ is
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n-2} k \left\lfloor \frac{n}{k} \right\rfloor = 1 + \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} k \left\lfloor \frac{n-1}{k} \right\rfloor
$$
and we assume $n>2$.

If we add $(n-1)\left \lfloor \frac{n}{n-1} \right\rfloor + n \left\lfloor \frac{n}{n}\right \rfloor + (n-1)\left\lfloor \frac{n-1}{n}\right\rfloor= (n-1) + (n) + (0) = 2 n - 1$ for $n>2$ on both the left and right hand side, we can rewrite the equations as 
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n} k \left\lfloor \frac{n}{k} \right\rfloor = 1 + (2n-1) + \sum_{k=1}^{n} k \left\lfloor \frac{n-1}{k} \right\rfloor
$$
Bringing both sums to the left and combining them then gives:
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n-2} k \left( \left\lfloor \frac{n}{k} \right\rfloor - \left\lfloor \frac{n-1}{k} \right\rfloor\right)= 2 n.
$$
On the left hand side we now have a sum over terms of the form:
$$
\left\lfloor \frac{n}{k} \right\rfloor - \left\lfloor \frac{n-1}{k} \right\rfloor
$$
Since $n$ and $n-1$ only differ by 1, these terms can only be either 1 or 0 whenever $k$ divides $n$ respectively when it doesn't. So only for $k|n$ there is a non-zero contribution on the left. We therefore find the equation
$$
\sum_{k|n}^{n} k \left( \left\lfloor \frac{n}{k} \right\rfloor - \left\lfloor \frac{n-1}{k} \right\rfloor\right)= \sum_{k|n}^{n} k = 2 n
$$
which is just the definition of a perfect number and establishes the equivalence.

Comment: So that's why Harry gave me the "hint" that σ$(P) = 2P$. I was wondering why we didn't use the restricted divisor function anyway, because it is just easier to write and less complicated.

Comment: Thanks so much :)